# What can be the different filetypes of videos shot using iPhone/iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, video

Is it mp4 or m4v or mov? I'm not sure. Please tell me what can be the different formats shot using iPhone or iPod Touch

THANX!!

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone and iPod touch only shoots one format:

H.264 in a .mov container - at 1280x720 at 30 FPS.